# Yield to foreach - refactor

Tags: scala, foreach, yield

I am newbie in Scala and I have following code:

```
   case _ => {
      val tempA = col2.head
      val collect = col2.drop(1)

      orderCol(collect).foreach {
        tmpCol => (0 until 10).foreach(
          a => (0 until 12).foreach {
            b => {
              val tmpBuild = TmpBuilder.build(tempA, b, a)

              if (isFiltered(tmpBuild, tmpCol)) {
                (tmpBuild :: tmpCol).sortBy(r => (r.tempA, r.B))
              }
            }
          }
        )
      }

//      for {
//        tmpCol <- orderCol(collect)
//        a <- 0 until 10
//        b <- 0 until 12
//        tmpBuild = TmpBuilder.build(tempA, b, a)
//        if (isFiltered(tmpBuild, tmpCol))
//      } yield (tmpBuild :: tmpCol).sortBy(r => (r.tempA, r.B))
    }
```

The part of commented code is working (comiling) fine. Since I am learning Scala I wanted to rewrite commented piece of code to the uncommented, like:

```
      orderCol(collect).foreach {
        tmpCol => (0 until 10).foreach(
          a => (0 until 12).foreach {
            b => {
              val tmpBuild = TmpBuilder.build(tempA, b, a)

              if (isFiltered(tmpBuild, tmpCol)) {
                (tmpBuild :: tmpCol).sortBy(r => (r.tempA, r.B))
              }
            }
          }
        )
      }
```

However I am getting following error:

```
Error:(18, 31) type mismatch;
found   : Unit
required: Set[List[test.TmpBuild]]
  orderCol(collect).foreach {
```

Do you know what is wrong with foreach loop? Should I use any map functions? 
I will appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: This `case` looks out of context. Consider rewriting your question in such a way that the problem is easy to reproduce. Here are a few hints: [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

The combination `for/yield` produces results, while `foreach` returns *Unit*. Use `flatMap+/map` instead.

```
  orderCol (collect).flatMap {
    tmpCol => (0 until 10).flatMap (
      a => (0 until 12).flatMap {
        b => TmpBuilder.build (tempA, b, a)
      }.filter (tmpBuild => isFiltered (tmpBuild, tmpCol)). map {
         (tmpBuild :: tmpCol).sortBy (r => (r.tempA, r.B))
      }
    )
  }
```

Comment: We might need more context. Meanwhile I changed the filtering to a call to filter. An [mcve] would be fine.